# how to check "or equ" in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Am a novice to Windows batch file and have been struggling with this script for more than 8 hours with several experiments.. but no luck...

This is my code

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR %%f IN (*.*) DO (
   echo %%f
   echo %%~xf

   IF %%~xf==".xml" |= ".java" (
     echo file needed
   ) ELSE(
     echo file not needed
     del %%f
   )

 )
```

1) Am not able to get |= to work; Getting "| was unexpected at this time." error

2) How to make this work for all files and subdir under this fodler?

3) I also tried the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%f IN (*.*) DO (
   set todel=yes
   echo %%~xf
   echo todel=%todel%
   IF %%~xf==".xml" (
     todel=no   
   )
   IF %%~xf==".java" (
     todel=no   
   )
   echo todel=%todel%
   IF %todel%=="yes" (
     del %%f
   )
)
```

todel is always empty. Guess I cant set it this way within the loop?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Probably help if you read the help file for the `IF` command.  Type `IF /?` at the command prompt.

Comment: The problem with your second set of code is you are inside a code block which requires the use of delayed expansion. You have to enable delayed expansion and then reference your variables with exclamation points instead of percent symbols. The IF command also does string comparisons. If you have quotes on one side of the comparison they must be on the other side.

Comment: Hi Squashman, thanks for your reply. Am not able to quite understand what you are saying though. Can you please put your words into code to show what am missing?

Comment: Reference your variables with delayed expansion: `echo todel=!todel!` and  Use quotes on both sides of your string comparisions: `IF "%%~xf"==".xml"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a better way of doing what you are effectively doing in this code, but here's a basic structure to help you understand better how cmd.exe does this.

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In (*.*) Do (
    If /I Not "%%~xA"==".xml" (
        If /I Not "%%~xA"==".java" (
            Echo %%~xA file not needed
            Echo Del %%A
        ) Else (
            Echo .java file needed
        )
    ) Else (
        Echo .xml file needed
    )
)
Timeout -1
```

Change `Echo Del %%A` to `Del %%A` on line 6 if you really want to let the script delete the files instead of just show you the delete command.

Comment: This works well. How do I make this code work for subdirs as well? TIA!

Comment: @user1164061, read the help for the `FOR` command by typing `FOR /?` at the command prompt.  You should see an option that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

One other option is to use the `DIR` command and pipe it to the `FINDSTR` command to just list the files you need to delete.

```
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%G IN (`dir /b /s *.* ^|findstr /E /V ".xml .java"`) DO del "%%G"
```